# Поиск по нескольким словами в текста на python?

Tags: python, строки

может кто знает как реализовать функцию, на python по поиску в тексте предложений по нескольким словами. Например у нас есть предложение: "Возможно ли встретиться нам сегодня вечером?" пользователь вводит "возможно ли" и предложение попадает в условный список, так как там есть такое словосочетание. Как такое можно реализовать на python? Как я понял мне нужно двигаться в сторону регулярок, но куда именно пока не понял.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону множеств

Comment: Приведённый пример можно просто через `in` проверять, предварительно переведя обе строки к одному регистру. Приведите больше примеров, что вы планируете искать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам нужно проверить есть ли несколько подряд идущих слов, то сделать это можно просто при помощи оператора `in`

```
text = "Возможно ли встретиться нам сегодня вечером?"
if "Возможно ли" in text:
    print("Словосочетание есть в тексте")
```

Если же надо проверить не подряд идущие слова, то необходимо текст разделить на слова методом `split`, преобразовать текст и слова во множества, и проверить полностью ли принадлежит множество слов множеству текста методом `issubset`

```
text = "Возможно ли встретиться нам сегодня вечером?"
if set(["Возможно", "вcтретиться"]).issubset(set(text.split())):
    print("Эти слова есть в тексте")
```

Comment: Хорошо бы ещё к одному регистру слова приводить